# HTML page numbering only if the number of pages is greater than 1

Tags: html, css, pdf-generation

I generate PDF files from HTML templates using java. And I need to make page numbering only if I have more than 1 page at all pages, including the first page. I can use css and HTML in templates. To provide numeration I use css:

```
@page { @bottom-right { content: element(footer); } }
#pagenumber:before { content: counter(page); }
#pagecount:before { content: counter(pages); }
@page { @bottom-right { content: counter(page) ' out of ' counter(pages); } }
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
<span id="pagenumber"></span> out of <span id="pagecount"></span>
</div>
```

So I always have pages numbering, not only when I have more than 1 page. I cant find solution in the internet. I need some kind of condition here.

Comment: What is the plugin/language that you are using to generate the PDF document? Just JAVA or any plugins?

Comment: WIAbstractPdfHtmlGenerator